# Excel Average of Lookup results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on an excel spreadsheet with a number of Football plays in a recent game and their gained yardage. The majority of plays were run multiple times, and have a row for every time they were run. Thus a single XLOOKUP function would only return the result of the first instance of the play. I am looking for a way to average out the value attached with each type of play. I would be extremely grateful to anyone who could help me solve this problem. I am a beginner to Excel and was somewhat perplexed by the other article I found that pertained to this.

https://www.get-digital-help.com/how-to-return-multiple-values-using-vlookup-in-excel/

Comment: AVERAGEIFS probably but could confirm after sample data and the expected result provided.

Comment: Or a pivot table.

Comment: Another option: since you are using `XLOOKUP` you have access to the new Dynamic Array functions.  Use `FILTER` to return the values you want, and appy `Average` to that

Comment: can we have a screenshot or something to get better visual clarity for what you want to average and the lookup values these depend upon pls? with what you have, we'll be guesstimating / hypothesizing solns based upon made up lookup codes/scores/runs.  Providing something specific will give better steer to facilitating a soln that you could (ideally) 'copy /paste' to resolve.../

Comment: (with a few minor tweaks)...

Comment: Otherwise, if you have column that comprises common lookup values for "plays [that] were run multiple times", e.g. RU-UK, 1-0 (former= countries, latter = score/gained yardage metric, whatever), then simple application of "Filter" (assuming you have Office 365 applicable Excel version) should do trick.  e.g. "=average(Filter(Yardage_range, 1*(Country_range = "RU-UK"))).  Better yet, just use '=Averageifs(Yardage_range, Country_range, "RU-UK")'....

Comment: @James Apologies for the delayed response. Here is a screenshot of my table. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dM62ONYwtAhF2ZRQ8nHFeswsIm7XE6G1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: np - did any of my proposals work? (e.g. averageifs no good?)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Copy and paste values of the play types to a new column
2. Highlight this data, then go Data-> Remove Duplicates to display only the unique plays
3. Use `=AVERAGEIF(column_range_of_play, type_of_play, column_range_of_yards)`

For example, if there are 100 plays categorized by the play type in column A and the yardage in column B, copy and paste column A to column D, remove duplicates, then in column E use `=AVERAGEIF(A1:100, D1, B1:B100)` and drag down